# visual studio 2005 ctrl+f not working

Tags: visual-studio-2005, replace

I recently re-installed visual studio 2005and not ctrl+f is not not working. It was working fine before the re-install.

Comment: You can customize shortcuts in Visual Studio. Check there what happened to Ctrl+F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing do should be to see if ctrl+f works at all you can do so in notepad or even in a browser.

If it is still not working try this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1103223.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...in command prompt run devenv /resetsettings